# how to load view after model is ready in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I would like to load my view i.e., generate the DOM only after my modal is completely ready. How can I do this in AngularJs without using the $timeout. Right now whenever I launch the page blank page is showing up and then slowly my data is getting populated. Any idea on how can I do this would be great.

Comment: Put the load part in a promise. Put your page in a big `ng-show`, and when promise is ready then display the page.

Comment: can also use resolve in routing, or use a loading mask. Not really complicated to figure out numerous ways to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you load the content you need to load the data with resolve. It keeps your view to wait till your data is ready.

This is one of my code with ui-router

```
  .state('statename',
 {
       url : "addressbarurl",
       templateUrl: 'templateurl',
       controller:'samplecontroller',
       resolve : {sampledetails : function(){
                        return "asdf";
                      }

                    }
 })
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('samplecontroller',['sampledetails',function(sampledetails){
console.log(sampledetails); //will output asdf

//your code here
}]);
```

Comment: hi Alaksandar, thanks for the answer, do you mean to say that our model 'sampledetails' should be ready before we pass it to the controller? don't we use resolve to pass the data to the controller and use that controller as a modal to the view?